# count NSMutableArray size till or from a specific word?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have got an array, I know how to count its elements, but I need to count elements until a specific word:

```
NSMutableArray *whatBondInFrame;

whatBondInFrame=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"red",@"red",@"red",@"gray",@"red",@"ran",@"gray",@"gray",nil];
```

I know `[ whatBondInFrame count]`  *but*, let's say I want to know how many elements I have till the first gray  **or from**  the word "ran".

How would I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested but it should work:

```
int loc = 0;
for (loc; loc < [array count]; loc++) {
    NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:loc];
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"ran"])
        break;
}
int length = array.count-loc;
```

this gives you the `count` from the first element named ran.
If you want to know how many elements there are before (till) the word 'ran' then replace the last line with

```
 int length = loc
```

Comment: thanks a lot thats a nice one, but i wanted something that apple gives you ,to do it simple. thanks anyway .

Comment: Nope there is no specific API to do that. Ive added some info to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `NSArray` method:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

Will return the index of the first occurrence on an object, so you can do:

```
NSUInteger firstRanIndex = [whatBondInFrame indexOfObject:@"ran"];
```

There is a companion method:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject inRange:(NSRange)range
```

Which restricts the search to a given range of the array. There is no method to find the last occurrence, for that you must loop with the above methods.

In conjunction with the `count` method you can get the numbers you want.